# MySQL Stored Procedured apply filter using IN and the filter value is coming from a parameter

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

As the title mention, i have a problem to apply simple filter on a query result using the operator (IN) in a MySQL Stored Procedured.

The simple example of the Stored Procedured looking like this

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_example`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_example`(
    `filter_uid_value` TEXT
)
BEGIN

SELECT
    a.id
    , a.name
    , a.uid
FROM
    employee_example a
WHERE 1=1
    AND a.uid IN (filter_uid_value)

END$$
DELIMITER;
```

so when i call this stored procedured, for example like this

```
CALL sp_example("du4jgjVRJGs,oKxU3SzV8CK");
```

the filter is not apply, i wonder how can fix this

Comment: What is the point of using `WHERE 1=1` ?

Comment: is just my habit to write ```WHERE 1=1```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_example`(
    `filter_uid_value` TEXT
)
SELECT id, name, uid
FROM employee_example
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(uid, filter_uid_value);
```

DELIMITER not needed.

---

```sql
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_example`(
    `filter_uid_value` TEXT
)
BEGIN
SET @sql := CONCAT( 'SELECT id, name, uid ',
                    'FROM employee_example ',
                    'WHERE uid IN ("',
                    REPLACE(filter_uid_value, ',', '","'),
                    '")' );
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
END;;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems like FIND_IN_SET is quite heavy. The query is running much slower than using the IN operator.

Comment: @NikoliusLau Of course. CSV is not good solution in general. Well, I'll add another option... done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your updated answer. I can use this solution.

Comment: @NikoliusLau You must update my second code. If the provided value contains dquote char or final slash char then the query will fail. You must check the provided parameter value and quote such problematic chars.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, will check on that.